# Set attribute to a data-element with a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to put a lot of data-element with the same content in multiple div.
How to define this content in a script in order to write it one time ?
I think I have to use a simple script but I can't find the solution. Thanks.

```
<div class="one" data-text"EXAMPLE"></div>
<div class="two" data-text"EXAMPLE"></div>  
<div class="three" data-text"EXAMPLE"></div>
<div class="four" data-text"EXAMPLE"></div>
<div class="five" data-text"EXAMPLE"></div>
```

Comment: What divs does this get applied to? What's the criteria

Comment: Couldn't you just use [jQuery attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) ?

Comment: $("div").attr("data-text","Example");

Comment: What's going to _consume_ this attribute?

Comment: In order to apply some :before and :after properties for a typography effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add a shared class to all of them you can target that class and add a data-attr. If you target just the `div` it's going to add it to every div on the page.

```
$(".target").attr("data-text", "TEXT");
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nn8ge6t9/)

Answer (score 2):

Add some additional class to all your divs. Like

```
<div class="one mydata" data-text"EXAMPLE"></div>
<div class="two mydata" data-text"EXAMPLE"></div>
```

etc.

then you can execute the following script :

```
$(".mydata").attr("data-text", "OTHER EXAMPLE");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have here the ways to use it:

jQuery (correct method, might not map to 'real' HTML attributes):

```js
$('#element').data('value_to_set',value);
value=$('#element').data('value_to_get');
```

jQuery (other method):

```js
$('#element').attr('data-value_to_set',value);
value=$('#element').attr('data-value_to_get');
```

Pure Javascript (method 1, for modern browsers and IE11+):

```js
document.getElementById('#element').dataset.value_to_set=value;
value=document.getElementById('#element').dataset.value_to_get;
```

Pure Javascript (method 2, for browsers with Javascript):

```js
document.getElementById('#element').setAttribute('data-value_to_set',value);
value=document.getElementById('#element').getAttribute('data-value_to_get');
```